# Changing useragent of Firefox with Selenium through options add_argument?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, user-agent, user-agent-switcher

The user agent is showing on the address bar like this `http://user-agent=mozilla/5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0;%20Win64;%20x64)%20AppleWebKit/537.36%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome/87.0.4280.88%20Safari/537.36`. Picture to illustrate the issue:

[image: Picture showing the problem]

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

option = Options()
option.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
option.set_preference("browser.link.open_newwindow", 3)
option.set_preference("browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction", 0)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=option)
```

How can I change the user agent of Firefox with Selenium through the option `add_argument`?

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "whatever you want")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Add argument adds commandline arguments for the firefox or Chrome binary. Firefox doenst have any user agent commandline option

Comment: but my code was working fine before reinstalling windows, maybe i have installed some packages before but i forgot them maybe...

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-reset-default-user-agent-firefox

Comment: These are the only allowed solutions , may be you have Installed some extension

Answer (score 1):

## Warning: FirefoxProfile is DEPRICATED

The normal method of using `FirefoxProfile` is now depricated and you must use `Options` instead.

## How to change FireFox User Agent using Options

Simply do the same as `FirefoxProfile` but with `Options` object instead like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
agent = " Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)"
options.set_preference("general.useragent.override", agent)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

### Using random User Agent from git

To use a random user agent you can just pull from this git list of useragents at random (requires `pip install requests`):

```
import requests,random
agents = requests.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pzb/b4b6f57144aea7827ae4/raw/cf847b76a142955b1410c8bcef3aabe221a63db1/user-agents.txt").text.split('\n')
agent = random.choice(agents)
```

### Using random user agent from pip package

There is a helpful package called [`random-user-agent`](https://github.com/Luqman-Ud-Din/random_user_agent) by installing through pip

```
pip install random-user-agent
```

Then to get a random agent:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
agent = UserAgent().random
```

### Full Example

Here is a full example of setting a random user agent for selenium using options:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.set_preference("general.useragent.override", UserAgent().random)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

Cheers